# How to make the test take an existing coin_id?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm, django-tests

My code

It is necessary that the test itself could substitute the existing coin_id, so that in the future the test does not fall, for example, due to the removal of a coin under id=2

```
class ModelTransactionTest(TestCase):
    @freeze_time(timezone.now())
    def test_auto_setting_date_if_field_empty(self):
        field = Transaction.objects.create(rubles_cost=1, purchase_price=1, amount=1, 
            dollars_cost=1, coin_id=2)
        self.assertEqual(timezone.now(), field.date)
```

Comment: Why don't you set up the appropriate coins _in the test_, so it's independent of what might be needed in other contexts?

Comment: Hey! A very good approach for setting up tests is to create all needed objects with each test, not globally. that way avoid dependencies between tests, which can create a lot of headache. This concept is explained very well here: https://youtu.be/ickNQcNXiS4?t=533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create coin instance in tests

```
class ModelTransactionTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        super().setUp()
        self.coin = Coin.objects.create(kwargs required to create object)

    @freeze_time(timezone.now())
    def test_auto_setting_date_if_field_empty(self):
        field = Transaction.objects.create(rubles_cost=1, purchase_price=1, amount=1, 
            dollars_cost=1, coin=self.coin)
        self.assertEqual(timezone.now(), field.date)
```